# How to give color kml line?

Tags: colors, line, kml

### Kml Line Color

Hi,
I am trying to change color kml lines. I want to change color of line each one. For example first blue, second red, etc..

My codes at below.. 
How can I make it?
I can just make to change general color .

---

```
<StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
    <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
    </Pair>

</StyleMap>

<Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">

    <LineStyle>
        <color>50000000</color>
        <width>8</width>
    </LineStyle>

</Style>

<Placemark id="ID_00000">
    <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
    <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>

        <LineString>


            <tessellate>first</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                30.55208275199055,39.77545668999021,0 30.55329917229911,39.7743291838848,0 30.553487499178,39.774210036146,0 30.55376134193491,39.77410216245037,0 30.55400914652402,39.77403635753819,0 30.5543003791806,39.77395726162271,0 30.55445586388359,39.7738989798837,0 30.55478077235974,39.77373535569645,0 30.55492616951969,39.77361530054731,0 30.55606546970367,39.77263540786894,0 30.55616710016928,39.7725381058988,0 30.55624520637499,39.77241189584878,0 30.5563118851529,39.77226176801565,0 30.55635319812838,39.77213478272165,0 30.55634200076624,39.77193092483321,0 30.55631906111245,39.771191719873,0 30.55622198159202,39.76863626781003,0 30.5561935513482,39.76798883121545,0 30.55618640911133,39.76765631919049,0 30.55607976315839,39.76463444473299,0 30.55606261438817,39.76439102113691,0 30.55597382368099,39.76429917777359,0 30.5558409415722,39.76423955310673,0 30.55570672038415,39.7642177832708,0 30.55555839482443,39.76424780545259,0 30.55536018072171,39.76430045304888,0 30.55513162700265,39.76436656311772,0 30.55279513132897,39.76499929438431,0 30.55145698551002,39.76535935794406,0 30.55081176257757,39.76555882903507,0 30.55003743872202,39.76576504058954,0 30.54755947208565,39.76642772092054,0 30.54481359682516,39.76720306212964,0 30.54441797766511,39.76728466001697,0 30.54413457737936,39.76731654324124,0 30.54385151335529,39.76733896210897,0 30.5434574609685,39.7673410865186,0 30.5429489871468,39.76735299552406,0 30.54265322200134,39.76736014071452,0 30.5396982877813,39.7674829780168,0 30.53625772778702,39.76767351479073,0 30.53578812258117,39.76769356874716,0 30.53546027699203,39.76776710492464,0 30.53526305210735,39.76779132657096,0 30.53509749830203,39.76778780860342,0 30.5349264883377,39.76776523291016,0 30.53474376966929,39.76773377407705,0 30.53409731811554,39.76761501777818,0 30.53376210730966,39.7675510664405,0 30.53327495925238,39.76744600005959,0 30.53188114065927,39.76712749227719,0 30.53113741386012,39.76697452767301,0 30.53035581760766,39.76680972424368,0 30.5299373607711,39.76674516861281,0 30.52944053972674,39.76673932321968,0 30.52887593384736,39.76674150239134,0 30.52842101785435,39.76676495764476,0 30.5264080559429,39.76694461098736,0 30.52603301732562,39.76696502484203,0 30.5254183412927,39.76699453147431,0 30.52517919109393,39.76701539095011,0 30.52502985254563,39.76704780277677,0 30.52491863768399,39.76706910659861,0 30.52464836541708,39.7671815661829,0 30.52313805091433,39.76778402332261,0 30.52291273317693,39.76790706690503,0 30.52269269774701,39.76805389973553,0 30.52218638569389,39.76848347496803,0 30.52173268572158,39.768814729151,0 30.52101160142468,39.76941491890977,0 30.52013484831262,39.77024854457439,0 30.51982504669052,39.77050236611645,0 30.51956599656533,39.77070991840461,0 30.51879199775974,39.77124988034783,0 30.51755808101385,39.77211124992451,0 30.51738690626452,39.77226385344608,0 30.51728284201428,39.77242736395041,0 30.51723992680929,39.7725969186458,0 30.51725918166938,39.77274412724389,0 30.51750656489119,39.77388591078061,0 30.5177954103205,39.77495738852652,0 30.51794771780237,39.77554996733092,0 30.51828023883764,39.77677683564761,0 30.51820802148492,39.77690788068335,0 30.51806119506965,39.77706574135599,0 30.51789034869962,39.77720888170314,0 30.51770825740611,39.77732336892879,0 30.51726009072993,39.77749845576437,0 30.51668740173768,39.77772296382176,0 30.51621418970355,39.77791171640408,0 30.51609563098926,39.77796600181452,0 30.51543044021505,39.77837320173492,0 30.51487638467662,39.77871901780135,0 30.51347263904215,39.77956717557719,0 30.51293398971048,39.77986816027232,0 30.50940917331127,39.7814546336846,0 30.50897220102404,39.78165834042027,0 30.50891325053533,39.78176125214873,0 30.50889654620845,39.78188401266556,0 30.50893537811716,39.78199849529264,0 30.50926958246813,39.78243185509649,0 30.51034946834446,39.78384936729862,0 30.51049997210012,39.78405408717125,0 30.5105381252234,39.78418749612191,0 30.51051546061802,39.78430539356028,0 30.5102723884096,39.78472356402966,0 30.50995303781935,39.78526406794016,0 30.50974449048328,39.78560053589698,0 30.50959029772633,39.78579137459551,0 30.50943661623847,39.78596801798854,0 30.50918207214894,39.78621826070349,0 30.50774449937931,39.78772721749933,0 30.50757995595733,39.78792171627243,0 30.50749152715242,39.78799084613388,0 30.50736153206627,39.78802119974625,0 30.50720854161327,39.78800844078165,0 30.50698217389574,39.78796453381413,0 30.50366684079857,39.78733087221538,0 30.50107737938489,39.78682709975562,0 30.50036845723828,39.78668088485895,0 30.49997360018618,39.78660257591444,0 30.49987087935947,39.78655774346461,0 30.49973375928648,39.7864458744634,0 30.49961641006889,39.78629654875916,0 30.49952222254462,39.78618560509537,0 30.4993709521726,39.78612551942442,0 30.49921813934804,39.78610801843487,0 30.49908149734451,39.78615242547821,0 30.49883188798869,39.78626542638547,0 30.49836997996701,39.78647802531139,0 30.49799358993334,39.78670193798943,0 30.49759999875201,39.7868923308432,0 30.49682610585513,39.78724498721488,0 30.49632687137183,39.78747097823592,0 30.49588403411171,39.7876650373705,0 30.49523690955533,39.78790677171427,0 30.49479458177331,39.78808663158435,0 30.49412784749101,39.78836108345269,0 30.49300660985405,39.78885622157366,0 30.49205577601575,39.78925854440151,0 30.4916152240481,39.78943377758046,0 30.49132231375628,39.78955529614549,0 30.49098732894288,39.78965222701463,0 30.490474303658,39.78975003983367,0 30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162,0
            </coordinates>

        </LineString>
            <LineString>
        <coordinates>
            30.55306933599353,39.76485789392094,0 30.55300989599834,39.76350172117805,0 30.55290770929984,39.76319929571931,0 30.55271870544885,39.76303568701522,0 30.55233428302535,39.76233800830583,0 30.55207013880492,39.76173258834482,0 30.5530882462863,39.76136711590753,0 30.55394543879455,39.76077178288264,0 30.55485307971753,39.76002821940597,0 30.5562854777982,39.75884462102884,0 30.55769800110098,39.75787713281138,0 30.56010341467413,39.75631251912146,0 30.56138934332899,39.7553640209978,0 30.56249988826194,39.75453464454295,0 30.56411346344861,39.75374027906172,0 30.56591261023536,39.75279843401238,0 30.56686029302946,39.7522528553724,0 30.56795085882791,39.75182902978272,0 30.56917600041085,39.75133123256144,0 30.57016876765188,39.75070560072842,0 30.57133100654567,39.74994553252327,0 30.57334756283363,39.74868460140477,0 30.57473200832074,39.747854457198,0 30.57536390725456,39.74742405091067,0 30.5772214658438,39.74637542629831,0 30.57876980431123,39.74524139381695,0 30.58048514615319,39.74386005927328,0 30.58116351679419,39.74328740894802,0 30.58333468728289,39.74158877889896,0 30.58419701353435,39.74090530604617,0 30.58466554236851,39.74057589329816,0 30.58483597077077,39.74054515231796,0 30.5852932925947,39.74089013625106,0 30.58584679429913,39.74147189526373,0 30.58588054308298,39.74169270778833,0 30.58569951637363,39.7418626449796,0 30.58487176671997,39.74226175784619,0 30.58462700110762,39.74238665552747,0 30.58443520707476,39.74224005544104,0 30.58398210011705,39.74174800819539,0 30.58363983638915,39.74142605588357,0 30.58355117447062,39.74139069967891,0
        </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>Second</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162,0 30.48974953456908,39.78976276661288,0 30.48965449843945,39.78967547341377,0 30.48958588897028,39.78953666344139,0 30.48958474637002,39.78939931385141,0 30.48956424732863,39.78861280365207,0 30.48950297689107,39.78844100510051,0 30.48936828011946,39.78826288166847,0 30.48914754698165,39.78808763078132,0 30.48851608986794,39.78761406332554,0 30.48800658277246,39.78722476828875,0 30.48780236152633,39.78710196125918,0 30.48767391053074,39.78708970809034,0 30.48754322073225,39.78713896570044,0 30.48741659712587,39.78724513533282,0 30.48643288176931,39.78813300438152,0 30.4861293550517,39.78837739850085,0 30.48517107487605,39.78907165888082,0 30.48499365368644,39.78922407761424,0 30.48493941502303,39.78936496149789,0 30.48496050002262,39.78946012548996,0 30.48502649330161,39.78963369602742,0 30.48523793839278,39.78997043293963,0 30.48532686640588,39.79005867758058,0 30.48545710181452,39.79009704344957,0 30.48558844632427,39.7901049686169,0 30.48578647961555,39.7900889522391,0 30.48795752585592,39.78993290085895,0 30.48953446884828,39.78982487904978,0 30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>3th</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                30.49611653728566,39.75432453676714,0 30.49605875478015,39.75407051619083,0 30.49603664825351,39.75365353749095,0 30.49598419841209,39.75356048773647,0 30.49588608679008,39.7534951765129,0 30.49529081512401,39.75323676336507,0 30.49469866973588,39.7529898429372,0 30.4945683152915,39.75299277243268,0 30.49447368877226,39.75303668741122,0 30.49435373361962,39.75316335550571,0 30.49423427052028,39.75337907923379,0 30.49425634551964,39.75348870817842,0 30.49435414333986,39.75356263126024,0 30.49611653728566,39.75432453676714,0 30.49656684816477,39.75452958072573,0 30.49693280213702,39.75459779878342,0 30.49716707145498,39.75460285362102,0 30.49747716715195,39.75456932989535,0 30.49774802120129,39.75448900006627,0 30.49800152882333,39.75437382635829,0 30.49822009215217,39.75426043103318,0 30.49960014668696,39.75359539913496,0 30.50027036630723,39.75327664227446,0 30.50040919645484,39.75324516473538,0 30.50052777316547,39.7532592094536,0 30.50063374125603,39.75331319635579,0 30.50069353051743,39.75340927462425,0 30.50071468167764,39.75354473436862,0 30.50079782161338,39.75487918907888,0 30.5008162010926,39.75522308206036,0 30.50084868873363,39.7557048133442,0 30.50090185525877,39.75588117672425,0 30.50098229811126,39.75602365859866,0 30.50107865381155,39.75613775896716,0 30.50122829891328,39.75632194539564,0 30.50154286415268,39.75678256429374,0 30.50203506891666,39.75747680186019,0 30.50301820541598,39.75888547967088,0 30.50317213826812,39.7591039161989,0 30.50323522673362,39.7592119129278,0 30.50323753526588,39.75932183287247,0 30.50321178306606,39.75939721830651,0 30.50313896002642,39.75950067383786,0 30.50297565371167,39.75971413671145,0 30.50280861175659,39.75995243240502,0 30.5026257584609,39.7602619490957,0 30.50256123377141,39.76042536522466,0 30.50242037262338,39.7608472716019,0 30.50238148392942,39.76093853135615,0 30.50228325417023,39.76110768451728,0 30.50201024930185,39.76153643925402,0 30.50181664609877,39.76179563513943,0 30.50148571363092,39.76214720126151,0 30.50131024348911,39.76236800911423,0 30.50124577188756,39.76252980981867,0 30.5012150629965,39.76268425911924,0 30.50112176748208,39.76317989651739,0 30.50086690280881,39.7644718121037,0 30.5008024529845,39.76477259712826,0 30.50077317005722,39.76506118315579,0 30.50078911490467,39.76525703090461,0 30.50079892995804,39.76538653500465,0 30.50084567904266,39.76577690124235,0 30.50092489535301,39.76636512052181,0 30.5009972046291,39.76691279748212,0 30.50103788366962,39.76723520551142,0 30.50112997263391,39.76735190678099,0 30.50126774774906,39.76742112007317,0 30.50144964236865,39.76742826984719,0 30.5031127846798,39.76752386562182,0 30.50418521134848,39.76756956654074,0 30.5053090558675,39.76760172355328,0 30.50619363853631,39.76763049980637,0 30.50685152806495,39.76765760660097,0 30.5075373296829,39.76768365550365,0 30.50839421440024,39.76778446798019,0 30.5090746115072,39.76784432220885,0 30.50932293231115,39.7678674277671,0 30.50949535516517,39.76790506056739,0 30.50965702661818,39.76795054097278,0 30.50996636251142,39.76808159388293,0 30.51038884614202,39.76826839398031,0 30.51086892275666,39.76848389605051,0 30.51113246913588,39.76860750028934,0 30.51181531098852,39.76894852952182,0 30.51310288299504,39.76957941234593,0 30.5134729308797,39.76978063552057,0 30.51391298602259,39.77000334585159,0 30.51432764725705,39.7702335890366,0 30.51475608530194,39.77048836203,0 30.51532586875268,39.77083017980958,0 30.51572996422598,39.771121589793,0 30.51610064353886,39.7713525004382,0 30.51685787692144,39.77183889416126,0 30.51701451042994,39.77196665925323,0 30.51712040811258,39.77210787974151,0 30.51717208166821,39.77224309222113,0 30.51718870933933,39.7723630128509,0 30.51723992680929,39.7725969186458,0 30.51725918166938,39.77274412724389,0 30.51750656489119,39.77388591078061,0 30.5177954103205,39.77495738852652,0 30.51794771780237,39.77554996733092,0 30.51816632200101,39.77621485229454,0 30.51831507302844,39.77650402085485,0 30.51841586312475,39.77661281610521,0 30.51851519555427,39.77664564037181,0 30.51859046364411,39.77664886642732,0 30.51867880821611,39.77663783053732,0 30.51875930529875,39.77661208505388,0 30.51887653313104,39.77655481047705,0 30.51904781060363,39.7764502197592,0 30.51939658315195,39.77624278625924,0 30.52004984459871,39.77595299683984,0 30.5204796684102,39.77584141186959,0 30.52093181194936,39.77570848568271,0 30.52113034901332,39.77566102533609,0 30.52129843371335,39.77564522865377,0 30.52153725317179,39.77564225342155,0 30.52207557756077,39.77569576459578,0 30.52286755063847,39.77579993145269,0 30.52350852782338,39.77591056345738,0 30.52375799213584,39.77596113035281,0 30.52388354323221,39.77602197736064,0 30.52397021599631,39.77611592481994,0 30.5240113280026,39.77625414034385,0 30.52410540523959,39.77690082877881,0 30.52416228166096,39.77712501495996,0 30.52426080107525,39.77753105283742,0 30.52447206756974,39.77823840890682,0 30.52466094610998,39.778886723574,0 30.52469108015091,39.77902186962818,0 30.5248442308531,39.7795412822563,0 30.52500342798525,39.78006422417006,0 30.52508694252848,39.78036330228639,0 30.52529066473786,39.78104787541239,0 30.52535225364643,39.78125761984605,0 30.525439580594,39.78139197365125,0 30.52555160394561,39.78147999785195,0 30.52580484477562,39.78165095229672,0 30.5259523867246,39.78175336046768,0 30.52607762060272,39.7817767616032,0 30.52619160529969,39.7817680306526,0 30.52632594635272,39.78171030112468,0 30.526356228988,39.78167267656754,0 30.52637876465446,39.78162053537065,0 30.52639028936387,39.78158729454488,0 30.52638804286219,39.78153462480223,0 30.52637541340293,39.78148332821803,0 30.52633995288514,39.78143473389911,0 30.52628389779053,39.78138410572269,0 30.52622362921051,39.78135028298729,0 30.52615952090598,39.78133680408053,0 30.52609779418761,39.78132910906757,0 30.52601891809282,39.78133858882605,0 30.52590206956408,39.78136958293604,0 30.52576858536721,39.78140341124442,0 30.52568758687982,39.78141444010055,0 30.52559522522062,39.78139652366104,0 30.52546476753162,39.78134590234594,0 30.52535225364643,39.78125761984605,0

            </coordinates>
        </LineString>


    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the polyline styles within a MultiGeometry, they will all be the same.  Separate them out as individual Placemarks, then you can control them separately.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20140822_lineColor.kml)

```
<Placemark id="ID_00000">
  <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7fff0000</color>
      <width>8</width>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>0</tessellate> 
    <coordinates>30.55208275199055,39.77545668999021 30.55329917229911,39.7743291838848 30.553487499178,39.774210036146 30.55376134193491,39.77410216245037 30.55400914652402,39.77403635753819 30.5543003791806,39.77395726162271 30.55445586388359,39.7738989798837 30.55478077235974,39.77373535569645 30.55492616951969,39.77361530054731 30.55606546970367,39.77263540786894 30.55616710016928,39.7725381058988 30.55624520637499,39.77241189584878 30.5563118851529,39.77226176801565 30.55635319812838,39.77213478272165 30.55634200076624,39.77193092483321 30.55631906111245,39.771191719873 30.55622198159202,39.76863626781003 30.5561935513482,39.76798883121545 30.55618640911133,39.76765631919049 30.55607976315839,39.76463444473299 30.55606261438817,39.76439102113691 30.55597382368099,39.76429917777359 30.5558409415722,39.76423955310673 30.55570672038415,39.7642177832708 30.55555839482443,39.76424780545259 30.55536018072171,39.76430045304888 30.55513162700265,39.76436656311772 30.55279513132897,39.76499929438431 30.55145698551002,39.76535935794406 30.55081176257757,39.76555882903507 30.55003743872202,39.76576504058954 30.54755947208565,39.76642772092054 30.54481359682516,39.76720306212964 30.54441797766511,39.76728466001697 30.54413457737936,39.76731654324124 30.54385151335529,39.76733896210897 30.5434574609685,39.7673410865186 30.5429489871468,39.76735299552406 30.54265322200134,39.76736014071452 30.5396982877813,39.7674829780168 30.53625772778702,39.76767351479073 30.53578812258117,39.76769356874716 30.53546027699203,39.76776710492464 30.53526305210735,39.76779132657096 30.53509749830203,39.76778780860342 30.5349264883377,39.76776523291016 30.53474376966929,39.76773377407705 30.53409731811554,39.76761501777818 30.53376210730966,39.7675510664405 30.53327495925238,39.76744600005959 30.53188114065927,39.76712749227719 30.53113741386012,39.76697452767301 30.53035581760766,39.76680972424368 30.5299373607711,39.76674516861281 30.52944053972674,39.76673932321968 30.52887593384736,39.76674150239134 30.52842101785435,39.76676495764476 30.5264080559429,39.76694461098736 30.52603301732562,39.76696502484203 30.5254183412927,39.76699453147431 30.52517919109393,39.76701539095011 30.52502985254563,39.76704780277677 30.52491863768399,39.76706910659861 30.52464836541708,39.7671815661829 30.52313805091433,39.76778402332261 30.52291273317693,39.76790706690503 30.52269269774701,39.76805389973553 30.52218638569389,39.76848347496803 30.52173268572158,39.768814729151 30.52101160142468,39.76941491890977 30.52013484831262,39.77024854457439 30.51982504669052,39.77050236611645 30.51956599656533,39.77070991840461 30.51879199775974,39.77124988034783 30.51755808101385,39.77211124992451 30.51738690626452,39.77226385344608 30.51728284201428,39.77242736395041 30.51723992680929,39.7725969186458 30.51725918166938,39.77274412724389 30.51750656489119,39.77388591078061 30.5177954103205,39.77495738852652 30.51794771780237,39.77554996733092 30.51828023883764,39.77677683564761 30.51820802148492,39.77690788068335 30.51806119506965,39.77706574135599 30.51789034869962,39.77720888170314 30.51770825740611,39.77732336892879 30.51726009072993,39.77749845576437 30.51668740173768,39.77772296382176 30.51621418970355,39.77791171640408 30.51609563098926,39.77796600181452 30.51543044021505,39.77837320173492 30.51487638467662,39.77871901780135 30.51347263904215,39.77956717557719 30.51293398971048,39.77986816027232 30.50940917331127,39.7814546336846 30.50897220102404,39.78165834042027 30.50891325053533,39.78176125214873 30.50889654620845,39.78188401266556 30.50893537811716,39.78199849529264 30.50926958246813,39.78243185509649 30.51034946834446,39.78384936729862 30.51049997210012,39.78405408717125 30.5105381252234,39.78418749612191 30.51051546061802,39.78430539356028 30.5102723884096,39.78472356402966 30.50995303781935,39.78526406794016 30.50974449048328,39.78560053589698 30.50959029772633,39.78579137459551 30.50943661623847,39.78596801798854 30.50918207214894,39.78621826070349 30.50774449937931,39.78772721749933 30.50757995595733,39.78792171627243 30.50749152715242,39.78799084613388 30.50736153206627,39.78802119974625 30.50720854161327,39.78800844078165 30.50698217389574,39.78796453381413 30.50366684079857,39.78733087221538 30.50107737938489,39.78682709975562 30.50036845723828,39.78668088485895 30.49997360018618,39.78660257591444 30.49987087935947,39.78655774346461 30.49973375928648,39.7864458744634 30.49961641006889,39.78629654875916 30.49952222254462,39.78618560509537 30.4993709521726,39.78612551942442 30.49921813934804,39.78610801843487 30.49908149734451,39.78615242547821 30.49883188798869,39.78626542638547 30.49836997996701,39.78647802531139 30.49799358993334,39.78670193798943 30.49759999875201,39.7868923308432 30.49682610585513,39.78724498721488 30.49632687137183,39.78747097823592 30.49588403411171,39.7876650373705 30.49523690955533,39.78790677171427 30.49479458177331,39.78808663158435 30.49412784749101,39.78836108345269 30.49300660985405,39.78885622157366 30.49205577601575,39.78925854440151 30.4916152240481,39.78943377758046 30.49132231375628,39.78955529614549 30.49098732894288,39.78965222701463 30.490474303658,39.78975003983367 30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="ID_00001">
  <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7f00ff00</color>
      <width>8</width>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <LineString>
    <coordinates>30.55306933599353,39.76485789392094 30.55300989599834,39.76350172117805 30.55290770929984,39.76319929571931 30.55271870544885,39.76303568701522 30.55233428302535,39.76233800830583 30.55207013880492,39.76173258834482 30.5530882462863,39.76136711590753 30.55394543879455,39.76077178288264 30.55485307971753,39.76002821940597 30.5562854777982,39.75884462102884 30.55769800110098,39.75787713281138 30.56010341467413,39.75631251912146 30.56138934332899,39.7553640209978 30.56249988826194,39.75453464454295 30.56411346344861,39.75374027906172 30.56591261023536,39.75279843401238 30.56686029302946,39.7522528553724 30.56795085882791,39.75182902978272 30.56917600041085,39.75133123256144 30.57016876765188,39.75070560072842 30.57133100654567,39.74994553252327 30.57334756283363,39.74868460140477 30.57473200832074,39.747854457198 30.57536390725456,39.74742405091067 30.5772214658438,39.74637542629831 30.57876980431123,39.74524139381695 30.58048514615319,39.74386005927328 30.58116351679419,39.74328740894802 30.58333468728289,39.74158877889896 30.58419701353435,39.74090530604617 30.58466554236851,39.74057589329816 30.58483597077077,39.74054515231796 30.5852932925947,39.74089013625106 30.58584679429913,39.74147189526373 30.58588054308298,39.74169270778833 30.58569951637363,39.7418626449796 30.58487176671997,39.74226175784619 30.58462700110762,39.74238665552747 30.58443520707476,39.74224005544104 30.58398210011705,39.74174800819539 30.58363983638915,39.74142605588357 30.58355117447062,39.74139069967891</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="ID_00002">
  <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7f0000ff</color>
      <width>8</width>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>0</tessellate>
    <coordinates>30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162 30.48974953456908,39.78976276661288 30.48965449843945,39.78967547341377 30.48958588897028,39.78953666344139 30.48958474637002,39.78939931385141 30.48956424732863,39.78861280365207 30.48950297689107,39.78844100510051 30.48936828011946,39.78826288166847 30.48914754698165,39.78808763078132 30.48851608986794,39.78761406332554 30.48800658277246,39.78722476828875 30.48780236152633,39.78710196125918 30.48767391053074,39.78708970809034 30.48754322073225,39.78713896570044 30.48741659712587,39.78724513533282 30.48643288176931,39.78813300438152 30.4861293550517,39.78837739850085 30.48517107487605,39.78907165888082 30.48499365368644,39.78922407761424 30.48493941502303,39.78936496149789 30.48496050002262,39.78946012548996 30.48502649330161,39.78963369602742 30.48523793839278,39.78997043293963 30.48532686640588,39.79005867758058 30.48545710181452,39.79009704344957 30.48558844632427,39.7901049686169 30.48578647961555,39.7900889522391 30.48795752585592,39.78993290085895 30.48953446884828,39.78982487904978 30.48992023625294,39.78979487334162</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="ID_00003">
  <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
  <Style>
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7fffff00</color>
      <width>8</width>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>0</tessellate>
    <coordinates>30.49611653728566,39.75432453676714 30.49605875478015,39.75407051619083 30.49603664825351,39.75365353749095 30.49598419841209,39.75356048773647 30.49588608679008,39.7534951765129 30.49529081512401,39.75323676336507 30.49469866973588,39.7529898429372 30.4945683152915,39.75299277243268 30.49447368877226,39.75303668741122 30.49435373361962,39.75316335550571 30.49423427052028,39.75337907923379 30.49425634551964,39.75348870817842 30.49435414333986,39.75356263126024 30.49611653728566,39.75432453676714 30.49656684816477,39.75452958072573 30.49693280213702,39.75459779878342 30.49716707145498,39.75460285362102 30.49747716715195,39.75456932989535 30.49774802120129,39.75448900006627 30.49800152882333,39.75437382635829 30.49822009215217,39.75426043103318 30.49960014668696,39.75359539913496 30.50027036630723,39.75327664227446 30.50040919645484,39.75324516473538 30.50052777316547,39.7532592094536 30.50063374125603,39.75331319635579 30.50069353051743,39.75340927462425 30.50071468167764,39.75354473436862 30.50079782161338,39.75487918907888 30.5008162010926,39.75522308206036 30.50084868873363,39.7557048133442 30.50090185525877,39.75588117672425 30.50098229811126,39.75602365859866 30.50107865381155,39.75613775896716 30.50122829891328,39.75632194539564 30.50154286415268,39.75678256429374 30.50203506891666,39.75747680186019 30.50301820541598,39.75888547967088 30.50317213826812,39.7591039161989 30.50323522673362,39.7592119129278 30.50323753526588,39.75932183287247 30.50321178306606,39.75939721830651 30.50313896002642,39.75950067383786 30.50297565371167,39.75971413671145 30.50280861175659,39.75995243240502 30.5026257584609,39.7602619490957 30.50256123377141,39.76042536522466 30.50242037262338,39.7608472716019 30.50238148392942,39.76093853135615 30.50228325417023,39.76110768451728 30.50201024930185,39.76153643925402 30.50181664609877,39.76179563513943 30.50148571363092,39.76214720126151 30.50131024348911,39.76236800911423 30.50124577188756,39.76252980981867 30.5012150629965,39.76268425911924 30.50112176748208,39.76317989651739 30.50086690280881,39.7644718121037 30.5008024529845,39.76477259712826 30.50077317005722,39.76506118315579 30.50078911490467,39.76525703090461 30.50079892995804,39.76538653500465 30.50084567904266,39.76577690124235 30.50092489535301,39.76636512052181 30.5009972046291,39.76691279748212 30.50103788366962,39.76723520551142 30.50112997263391,39.76735190678099 30.50126774774906,39.76742112007317 30.50144964236865,39.76742826984719 30.5031127846798,39.76752386562182 30.50418521134848,39.76756956654074 30.5053090558675,39.76760172355328 30.50619363853631,39.76763049980637 30.50685152806495,39.76765760660097 30.5075373296829,39.76768365550365 30.50839421440024,39.76778446798019 30.5090746115072,39.76784432220885 30.50932293231115,39.7678674277671 30.50949535516517,39.76790506056739 30.50965702661818,39.76795054097278 30.50996636251142,39.76808159388293 30.51038884614202,39.76826839398031 30.51086892275666,39.76848389605051 30.51113246913588,39.76860750028934 30.51181531098852,39.76894852952182 30.51310288299504,39.76957941234593 30.5134729308797,39.76978063552057 30.51391298602259,39.77000334585159 30.51432764725705,39.7702335890366 30.51475608530194,39.77048836203 30.51532586875268,39.77083017980958 30.51572996422598,39.771121589793 30.51610064353886,39.7713525004382 30.51685787692144,39.77183889416126 30.51701451042994,39.77196665925323 30.51712040811258,39.77210787974151 30.51717208166821,39.77224309222113 30.51718870933933,39.7723630128509 30.51723992680929,39.7725969186458 30.51725918166938,39.77274412724389 30.51750656489119,39.77388591078061 30.5177954103205,39.77495738852652 30.51794771780237,39.77554996733092 30.51816632200101,39.77621485229454 30.51831507302844,39.77650402085485 30.51841586312475,39.77661281610521 30.51851519555427,39.77664564037181 30.51859046364411,39.77664886642732 30.51867880821611,39.77663783053732 30.51875930529875,39.77661208505388 30.51887653313104,39.77655481047705 30.51904781060363,39.7764502197592 30.51939658315195,39.77624278625924 30.52004984459871,39.77595299683984 30.5204796684102,39.77584141186959 30.52093181194936,39.77570848568271 30.52113034901332,39.77566102533609 30.52129843371335,39.77564522865377 30.52153725317179,39.77564225342155 30.52207557756077,39.77569576459578 30.52286755063847,39.77579993145269 30.52350852782338,39.77591056345738 30.52375799213584,39.77596113035281 30.52388354323221,39.77602197736064 30.52397021599631,39.77611592481994 30.5240113280026,39.77625414034385 30.52410540523959,39.77690082877881 30.52416228166096,39.77712501495996 30.52426080107525,39.77753105283742 30.52447206756974,39.77823840890682 30.52466094610998,39.778886723574 30.52469108015091,39.77902186962818 30.5248442308531,39.7795412822563 30.52500342798525,39.78006422417006 30.52508694252848,39.78036330228639 30.52529066473786,39.78104787541239 30.52535225364643,39.78125761984605 30.525439580594,39.78139197365125 30.52555160394561,39.78147999785195 30.52580484477562,39.78165095229672 30.5259523867246,39.78175336046768 30.52607762060272,39.7817767616032 30.52619160529969,39.7817680306526 30.52632594635272,39.78171030112468 30.526356228988,39.78167267656754 30.52637876465446,39.78162053537065 30.52639028936387,39.78158729454488 30.52638804286219,39.78153462480223 30.52637541340293,39.78148332821803 30.52633995288514,39.78143473389911 30.52628389779053,39.78138410572269 30.52622362921051,39.78135028298729 30.52615952090598,39.78133680408053 30.52609779418761,39.78132910906757 30.52601891809282,39.78133858882605 30.52590206956408,39.78136958293604 30.52576858536721,39.78140341124442 30.52568758687982,39.78141444010055 30.52559522522062,39.78139652366104 30.52546476753162,39.78134590234594 30.52535225364643,39.78125761984605</coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```